# Is low-power (or low-current) charging better for the battery in a phone?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

For a long period of time (4 years) for my older phone (Xiaomi Redmi 4X) I used a charger that has 0.7A output.  I think the battery is in very good condition. Now I have a Google Pixel 4a and its charger uses 3A output (5V * 3A = 15W.) I'm thinking about using my old charger with 0.7A to charge the Pixel overnight. Will it be better for battery lifespan or not ?

Comment: You will need to check the datasheet/specifications for your Pixel phone. It might require higher current capability from the charger to function properly.

Comment: Slower charge is better for lifespan, at least to a point.

Comment: **If** the phone charges from that charger and **IF** it doesn't overload the charger (make sure it doesn't get very hot, slightly warm is OK) then yes, this is probably a good idea and indeed that might (not saying that it will, it might) increase the battery lifetime. Do realize that the phone will only charge with a high current (fast charge) when the battery is between 30% - 70% as almost empty / almost full batteries should never be fast charged. The charging circuit in the phone will take care of this for you.

Comment: "*I used a charger ...*" Be aware that you've used a **power supply**. The charger is in the phone. The power supply will signal its current capability to the phone and the phone should not draw more than the PSU's rating.